# To get exact position in unity 3d

Tags: c#, vector, position, unity-game-engine

i declared

```
public Vector3 floorPosition;
```

in class. In start function i given

```
floorPosition = new Vector3(0.000f,0.500f,-8.250f);
```

i tried to instantiate a gameobject in floorPosition. 
But object comes in **(0.0, 0.5, -8.3)**.
 Automatically it get rounds.
What i have to do to get gameobject in exact position.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Something like `print(floorPosition.toString());` will give the same wrong results. Something like `print(floorPosition.toString(F4));` will probably give you the correct result. Are you sure you initiate the Vector3 like you wrote in your question?

Comment: Can you try making `floorPosition` `private` instead of `public`?

Comment: When you say the object "comes in" with the rounded positions, what do you mean? Are you seeing those numbers when output out the value in the console? If so, can you share the output code? (In that case it's likely the output is just automatically rounding them for display without changing the underlying values.) Or do you actually see those rounded numbers in the inspector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weird thing is that if you type

```
    floorPosition = new Vector3(0.0f,0.5f,-8.250f);
    transform.position = floorPosition;
```

The inspector **will show the exact position** you asked for (so I think you object is actually in the right spot) but the Debug.Log() will round it.